# How to download a pdf using php cURL from url?

Tags: php, pdf, curl, download

Hi I am trying to download the following file with PHP (I want to download it every day): http://www.borkumer-zeitung.de/wp-content/uploads/Zeitung/2019/08/BZ_020819.pdf

When I enter the url in my browser I can open the PDF just fine. But when I try to download it using cURL I get redirected to a login page.

I tried different settings for curl_setopt but nothing seems to work. The code works but instead of downloading the pdf I get redirected to: http://www.borkumer-zeitung.de/anmelden/ and the content of this page is downloaded.

```
This is my code: 

$url = "http://www.borkumer-zeitung.de/wp-content/uploads/Zeitung/2019/08/BZ_020819.pdf";
$saveTo = "newspaper/newspaper.pdf";


//Open file handler.
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');

//If $fp is FALSE, something went wrong.
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}


//Create a cURL handle.
$ch =curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.borkumer-zeitung.de/3d-flip-book/02-08-2019/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch);

//If there was an error, throw an Exception
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//Get the HTTP status code.
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Close the cURL handler.
curl_close($ch);

//Close the file handler.
fclose($fp);

if($statusCode == 200){
    echo 'Downloaded!';
} else{
    echo "Status Code: " . $statusCode;
}
```

I would love to get a hint or the solution to be able to download this file on my server :)

Comment: I get redirected to the login page in the browser as well. You may need to set some cookies / "login" your script before downloading

Comment: Target the URL where you need to log in and pass along the proper credentials. That page likely sets a cookie value that indicates you are logged in which is what allows you to download the PDF. Save the cookies from the log in page then pass them to the cURL call to download the PDF.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much :) I will give it a try and will report back!